# How to create BLE state listener for Xamarin iOS Plugin.Ble

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cbcentralmanager, plugin.bluetoothle

I have managed to achieve this for Android and I hope there is a solution for iOS. I'm using Plugin.BLE and I'm trying to create event listener which should sit in Xamarin iOS > AppDelegate level which will detect IBleCentralManagerDelegate.UpdatedState changes.
Reason: I would like to trap BLE states while user performs PIN pairing

So far I have:

```
internal class SimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate : CBCentralManagerDelegate
{
    public override void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager central)
    {
        var state = central.State;
    }

    public override void FailedToConnectPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSError error)
    {
        base.FailedToConnectPeripheral(central, peripheral, error);
    }

    public override void ConnectedPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral)
    {
        base.ConnectedPeripheral(central, peripheral);
    }

    [Export("centralManager:didUpdateANCSAuthorizationForPeripheral:")]
    public void DidUpdateAncsAuthorization(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral)
    {
        var test = peripheral.IsConnected;
    }
}
```

I'm getting only status poweredOn or poweredOff and other statuses or events are not firing.

Comment: As far as I know, iOS does not expose this information.

Comment: Would you know what should the correct workflow be when connecting to the BLE device with pin request be? To be more specific, how do I know, when did the user finish bonding?

Comment: You don't, and that is a thing where Apple hasn't really thought at all. iOS apps unfortunately can't know the current security level of the BLE connection and cannot enforce one either.

Comment: Oh great! You saved me some headache, thank you.